# what's %b1(b one, not b L) in `xorb %b1, %b1`?

Tags: linux, assembly

I am reading the `copy_from_user` function, in `copy_from_user` function, the macro `__get_user_asm` is used.

there is a mmap syscall in linux, mmap syscall will call function `copy_from_user`. this function will use the macro `__get_user_asm` if the size is constant. the content of `__get_user_asm` is

```
#define __get_user_asm(x, addr, err, itype, rtype, ltype, errret)   \
asm volatile("1:    mov"itype" %2,%"rtype"1\n"      \
         "2:\n"                     \
         ".section .fixup,\"ax\"\n"             \
         "3:    mov %3,%0\n"                \
         "  xor"itype" %"rtype"1,%"rtype"1\n"       \
         "  jmp 2b\n"                   \
         ".previous\n"                  \
         _ASM_EXTABLE(1b, 3b)               \
         : "=r" (err), ltype(x)             \
         : "m" (__m(addr)), "i" (errret), "0" (err))
```

when i try to translate 
`__get_user_asm(*(u8 *)dst, (u8 __user *)src, ret, "b", "b", "=q", 1);` to the real source,

````
1： movb %2,%b1\n
2:\n
.section .fixup, "ax" \n
3: mov %3, %0 \n
 **xorb %b1, %b1\n**
 jmp 2b\n
.previous\n

: "=r" (ret), =q(dst)
:"m"(dst), "i"(1), "0"(ret)

.quad "1b", "2b"\n
.previous\n```
````

,
there are somewhere i can't understand.

1, in `xorb %b1, %b1`, what's `%b1`(b one, not b L)?

2, in `jmp 2b`, is `2b` a label or a memroy address? if `2b` is a label, how can i find this lable?

3,  what's the function of `.quad "1b", "2b"`?

where can i get the knowledge that make me to understand the linux kernel source in semantics layer?

Comment: [`xorb %b1, %b1` just sets `%b1` to 0.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and)

Comment: yeah， i know the thing that sentence do. but i don't know what's %b1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for gcc's extended asm, we see that %1 refers to the second parameter (because parameter numbers are zero based).  In your example, that's `dst`.

Adding `b` (ie %b1) is described [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86Operandmodifiers):

```
Modifier Description                             Operand  masm=att  masm=intel
b        Print the QImode name of the register.  %b0      %al       al
```

`jmp 2b` means look backward for a label named `2`.

The `.quad` directive is defined [here](https://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gas/gas_7.html#SEC111):

> .quad expects zero or more bignums, separated by commas. For each
>   bignum, it emits an 8-byte integer. If the bignum won't fit in 8
>   bytes, it prints a warning message; and just takes the lowest order 8
>   bytes of the bignum.

As for where to get info, hopefully the links I have provided help.

Answer (score 0):

XOR any register with itself sets it to zero. So %B1 = 0.